# What is the difference between these 2 sentences with quantifiers?

Tags: logic

I'm practicing writing FOL sentences and I have the following sentences. The first sentence is the solution I provided and the second is the correct solution ( per the solutions manual).The difference is where I've placed ∃z. I understand there is a difference in scope but I don't understand how that difference is applied to the predicates.

1. ∀x (Txi => ∃y***∃z***(Txy ∧ Tyz ∧ Vz))
2. ∀x (Txi => ∃y(Txy ∧ **∃z**(Tyz ∧ Vz))

Comment: These two sentences are logically equivalent. In general, [existential quantifier does not distribute over conjunction](https://nokyotsu.com/qscripts/2014/07/distribution-of-quantifiers-over-logic-connectives.html), but in this case the first parenthesized predicate does not contain z, so is not affected by the shift.

Answer (score 1):

Both solutions are correct: Since z does not occur free in Txy, the ∃z has no effect on it, and the two formalizations are logically equivalent.

In general, you can move existential and universal quantifiers between the right-hand side of a conjunction resp. implication and the front, provided that the left-hand side does not contain free occurrences of the binding variable:

```
A ∧ ∃xB ≡ ∃x(A ∧ B), if x not free in A
A → ∀xB ≡ ∀x(A → B), if x not free in A
```

You can find a more comprehensive list of when formulas with the quantifier outside vs. inside a subformula are logically equivalent e.g. on [the Wikipedia article on prenex normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenex_normal_form).